# Deciphering of difficult handwriting

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

[image]I have tried to transcribe a difficult handwritten text. My try runs like this:

*Die theologischen Professoren hatten von ihm **eigentlich eben genug** nur gehört, ein Vorurtheil gegen diesen "modernen Rationalismus", wie es systematisch hieß; zu fügen auch mich hatte dieß Vorurtheil angesteckt; es war mir zu **lens** durch ein allgemeines Verdammungsurtheil gegen das System, **wieder schweren es das Durcharbeitens überhaben zu sein**.*

Any better proposals, especially when it comes to the text in bold ...?

Comment: It seems that I didn't succeed with attaching a picture of the handwriting in question!

Comment: Do you need help? You can edit the question and click on the image-button :)

Comment: Quite the interesting text snippet (to me at least)! Care to share more details as to who, what and when? Also see my answer below.

Comment: @Helge: Please include your context of that snippet into the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Marquino, thank you for your excellent help. The snippet I posted is from a letter written ca 1846 from the then young Marcus Jacob Monrad (later a renowned Norwegian professor of philosophy) to Karl Friedrich Werder de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Werder in Berlin. I would be glad to share a copy of the original manuscript as well as my incomplete (and faulty) transcription of the complete letter with you. However, I do not find any software function making it possible to correspond in private with you? Kind regards Helge

Comment: Why did you delete your question concerning Vaihinger's letter? I had a look to and I think I could decipher most of it.

Comment: I have added a complete transcription of Vaihinger's letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a line-by-line **transcription** of what is supposed to be the **final version**.

The parts in **bold** are the result of cancellations, substitutions or other changes.
A few corrections to the punctuation are in [square brackets].
I also included in (round brackets) the rest of the first and last line, which you omitted.

> (der hiesigen Universität nicht gekannt.)
> Die theologischen Professoren
> hatten von ihm **eben genug gehört, um** Vorurtheil
> gegen diesen “modernen Rationalismus”, wie es systematisch hieß[,]
> **zu hegen**[;] **auch** mich hatte dieß Vorurtheil angesteckt; es war mir zu
> lieb[,] durch ein allgemeines Verdammungsurtheil gegen das
> System, **der schweren Mühe des Durcharbeitens** überhoben
> zu sein.
> (Aber **dieß[e]** Befreiung war ein gewaltsamer,)

A loose **paraphrase**:

> The professors knew little about him – just enough to harbor a prejudice against his “rationalism”.
> This prejudice had also caught on to me: it was all too convenient for me, by subscribing to a wholesale condemnation of the system, to be relieved from doing the heavy work of going through [his writings].

The word you tentatively read as “lens” is “lieb”, in the meaning “willkommen, angenehm”. “fügen” is actually “hegen”: to harbor (a prejudice).

Finally, here is a reconstruction of the **parts that were crossed out or changed** (the ones in bold above).
In the second-to-last case, there seem to have been 3 layers before the final version, which I labelled (1)-(4).
Conjectures for unfinished words are in {braces}.

> - eigentlich nur gehört, und hegten nur [...] systematisch hieß;
> - mich hatte dieß Vorurtheil auch
> - (1) der schweren Arbeit[,] es mir anzu{eignen}
>   (2) der schweren Arbeit[,] es zu durchgeh{en}
>   (3) einer schweren Mühe
>   (4) der schweren Mühe des Durcharbeitens [final version].
> - dies Gefühl der Befreiung